# Input click can't be triggered programanticly on iOS <12

Tags: javascript, css, ios, mobile-safari, react-dropzone

I'm having an issue with triggering the opening of a file dialogue on older iOS devices, specifically, the issue seems to be on devices that still run iOS 12.

I'm using the React-Dropzone package to create a dropzone for files, but also adding a way to tab the area to open the file dialogue to select files.

I then use Hammerjs to detect onTab events.

What I can establish, by adding an alert to be fired when `onTab` is called, is that the `onTab` event is firing and that it is the functions that are meant to open the dialogue that is not triggering the file dialogue to open on older iOS devices.

```js
const FileUploadDropzone = () => {
...
        const {getRootProps, getInputProps, open, inputRef} = useDropzone({
            // Disable click and keydown behavior
            noClick: true,
            noKeyboard: true,
        });

        const handleTap = useCallback(() => {
            // specific function created by React-Dropzone to open the dialog
            open();
            // also tried to trigger the input click directly using a ref (have confirmted that the input is correctly referenced)
            inputRef.current.click();
        }, [allowInteract, uploading, open]);

        return (
            <Hammer onTap={handleTap}>
                <div {...getRootProps()}>
                    <input {...getInputProps()}/>
                    {children}
                </div>
            </Hammer>
        );
    };
```

From what I have read, the input cannot have styles set to `display:none`, if it does then you cannot programmatically trigger opening the file dialogue.

So I have set the styles as following:

```css
input {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
  }
```

What I've also tried to do is to wrap the input and the child element passed to the component in a label, hoping that clicking on a label to open the dialogue will be better supported, but even that is not working.

So now I am at a loss, I don't understand how to get this to work on these older iOS < 12 devices.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to an issue with fact that Safari on iOS 12 does not like it when there is any delay between the custom click event and until the input click event is called programmatically. Since the input in my case is deeply nested into the DOM, it causes an issue when the bubbling of the event takes to long.

To get around this issue, I had to create a hack, to append the file input into the DOM to make it as shallow of a grandchild as I could of the `<body>`.

I followed this article to utilise React.createPortal to append the input outside of the component. https://www.jayfreestone.com/writing/react-portals-with-hooks

I created a function to create an empty div at the bottom of the top `<div>` off the React application.

```js
function usePortal(cssSelector) {
    const rootElemRef = React.useRef(document.createElement('div'));

    useEffect(
        function setupElement() {
            const {current} = rootElemRef;
            const parentElem = document.querySelector(cssSelector);
            parentElem?.appendChild(current);
            return function removeElement() {
                current.remove();
            };
        },
        [id]
    );

    return rootElemRef.current;
}
```

Then created a component that would append its child a custom `div`, created by the function above

```js
const Modal = ({children}) => {
    const target = usePortal('#react-root-div');
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, target);
};
```

And then simply wrap the input element with the Modal component and it will be appended (almost) to the bottom of the DOM tree.

```
    <Modal>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
    </Modal>
```